# OpenSSL X509 Verify Signature with CA

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, x509

I have a root certificate which I created based on a previously provided keypair (private & public). The certificate is called Root CA in file `rootca.crt`.

I've now been tasked with verifying a given signature with the Root CA.

I'm fairly sure this needs to be done through X509 but I'm not familiar with the command? The signature which I need to verify was supplied in Base64 and I've decoded it and converted to binary, so I believe the final step I'm missing is an OpenSSL X509 verify command, but that doesn't seem to exist?

Any advice would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to verify? That the signature on the CA certificate is good? That the public key in the CA certificate matches the private key? Or that an end entity certificate (like a client certificate or server certificate) was signed by the CA?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `openssl verify` command.

```
openssl verify -CAfile rootca.crt certificate
```

See also the `verify(1)` man page.